# Bar chart with min and max values of same show the bar in the zeroth position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

#### What is the problem?

While passing the same values for the min and max in bar chart it shows the bar in a single line in zeroth position.
I am using the react-native-svg-charts [plugin](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts)

#### When does it happen?

When passing the same values for both min and max

#### What platform?

- [x]  iOS
- [x]  Android

React Native version: 0.55.4

```js
let tempData = [
      {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32},
      {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32},
      {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32},
      {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32},
      {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32},
      {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}, {'value': 32}
    ];
    const barData = [
      {
        data: tempData,
        svg: {
          fill: HistrogramCharts.minColor
        }
      },
      {
        data: tempData,
        svg: {
          fill: HistrogramCharts.maxColor
        }
      }
    ];

           <BarChart
              style={styles.histogramChats}
              data={barData}
              yAccessor={({ item }) => item.value}
              contentInset={HistrogramCharts.verticalContentInset}
            >
              <Grid svg={HistrogramCharts.gridSvg} />
              <LabelMin />
              <LabelMax />
            </BarChart>
```

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: yes that's expected behaviour what you want to do with it ?

Comment: @DhavalPatel How come it should show the bar in 32 right